# Memory Not Given Back Until Files Deleted?

Tags: memory, double, printf

We ran into a strange problem with some of our in-house developed applications and thought it was something deep in the code but then we wrote a quick sample to test it, we experienced the same issue.

Here's the code for the sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int COUNT = 750000;

   double x[100];
   double y[100];

   FILE *OutputFile1;
   FILE *OutputFile2;
   FILE *OutputFile3;
   FILE *OutputFile4;
   FILE *OutputFile5;
   FILE *OutputFile6;
   FILE *OutputFile7;
   FILE *OutputFile8;
   FILE *OutputFile9;

   OutputFile1 = fopen("Output_file_1.dat","w");
   OutputFile2 = fopen("Output_file_2.dat","w");
   OutputFile3 = fopen("Output_file_3.dat","w");
   OutputFile4 = fopen("Output_file_4.dat","w");
   OutputFile5 = fopen("Output_file_5.dat","w");
   OutputFile6 = fopen("Output_file_6.dat","w");
   OutputFile7 = fopen("Output_file_7.dat","w");
   OutputFile8 = fopen("Output_file_8.dat","w");
   OutputFile9 = fopen("Output_file_9.dat","w");

/* Do stuff in here */
   /* Initialize the arrays */
   for( i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      x[i] = 2.50 * (double)i;
      y[i] = 10.0 * (double)i;
   }   
   printf("Initialized the x and y arrays\n");
   /* Write junk to files */
   for( i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
   {
      printf("Outer loop %d\n", i);
      for( j = 0; j < 100; j++)
      {
         fprintf(OutputFile1," %e", x[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile2," %e", x[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile3," %e", x[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile4," %e", x[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile5," %e", x[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile6," %e", y[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile7," %e", y[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile8," %e", y[j]);
         fprintf(OutputFile9," %e", y[j]);
      }
      fprintf(OutputFile1,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile2,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile3,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile4,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile5,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile6,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile7,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile8,"\n");
      fprintf(OutputFile9,"\n");
   }

/* End doing stuff here */
   fflush(OutputFile1);
   fclose(OutputFile1);
   fflush(OutputFile2);
   fclose(OutputFile2);
   fflush(OutputFile3);
   fclose(OutputFile3);
   fflush(OutputFile4);
   fclose(OutputFile4);
   fflush(OutputFile5);
   fclose(OutputFile5);
   fflush(OutputFile6);
   fclose(OutputFile6);
   fflush(OutputFile7);
   fclose(OutputFile7);
   fflush(OutputFile8);
   fclose(OutputFile8);
   fflush(OutputFile9);
   fclose(OutputFile9);

   return(0);
}
```

So, here's what happens when you run this.  If you run this in one terminal window and run top in another while it's running, you'll notice your memory being eaten away.  It takes about 8 minutes for it to run and when it's finished, the system doesn't give the memory back, until the files are deleted. Once the files are deleted, all of the memory is released back to the system.

It's just C with the latest gcc compiler, CentOs 6.3.

Are we missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The system doesn't give the memory back". How do you know? There is a difference between "memory reported as free by `top`", and "memory you can use". This is because disk I/O is stored in cache when possible - that way, if you need to use the same file again, the information is already available in memory - faster to access. Once you delete a file, it's no longer useful to keep in cache - so the cache is cleared.

Another way to look at this is to use the `free` command. Doing this on my Linux box, I see the following:

```
             total       used       free    shared    buffers    cached
Mem:      66005544   65559292     446252         0     199832   60332160
-/+ buffers/cache:    5027300   60978244
Swap:      1044216       1884    1042332
```

The key line is the one that says "`-/+ buffers/cache`" . You can see that the first line tells me "446M free" - not a lot on a 64G machine. But the second line says "only joking, you have 60 G free". That is the *real* "free memory".

See whether that line "gives back memory" without having to delete the files. I think you will find it does.

Answer (score 0):

The system caches these files for quick access at the next time. Since the memory isn't used by an application it's used for caching. The cache is freed if the files are gone or an other application needs more memory to run.

See: [Linux Memory Management](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/Linux%20Memory%20Management.htm)